# ORA 02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, constraints

I have 2 tables : userphone and cellphone.I need to add a foreign key (brand) but it keeps giving me the following error:

> ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

```
 CREATE TABLE CELLPHONE (
 NR NUMBER(12,0) PRIMARY KEY CHECK (NR LIKE '35566%' OR NR LIKE '35567%'),
 BRAND VARCHAR2(10)
 );

CREATE TABLE USERPHONE (

NR_CLIENT NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
NAME VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
BRAND VARCHAR2 (10),
CONSTRAINT FK_BRAND FOREIGN KEY (BRAND) REFERENCES CELLPHONE (BRAND)

)
```

Now before  I know there are many posts about this issue but I tried everything

Comment: read about and understand what is `relations, unique, primary and foreign key,` before creating them, `you did them all incorrect` in your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read about foreign keys:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

> A FOREIGN KEY in one table points to a PRIMARY KEY in another table.

Brand is not a primary key in your CELLPHONE table.

You could create a BRAND table to store your unique brands (with a primary key) and then create a foreign key in both tables referencing it.